# Why does a false statement still execute?

Tags: c++, if-statement, return, execute

I have this code...

```
void drawMap(void)
{
    if (false)
        return;

    for(auto iter = this->m_layers.begin(); iter != m_layers.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if ((*iter)->get() == NULL)
            continue;
        PN::draw((*iter)->get(), b2Vec2(0,0), true, 0);
    }
}
```

If I'm not mistaken it should NEVER execute...but it does...and when I change

```
    if (false)
      return;
```

to

```
    if (false)
       return;
    else
       return;
```

it doesn't execute at all now, but how can that first statement NOT be false? *grabs headache pills*

P.S. I only did this 'cause I was debugging and noticed my code was drawing to the screen when it wasn't supposed to.

Comment: You really have `if (false)` in your code, or something else that you think is `if (false)`?

Comment: Huh??? The `if` statement will always fail, so the `return` inside its block will never execute. Any decent compiler will remove the whole thing.

Comment: If the problem was that you were drawing when you shouldn't, then your question is backwards. You want the `return` to execute, but it doesn't because the condition is false.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `#define` that changes the meaning of "false"?

Comment: This is why I prefer to *almost always* use `if (...) {...} else {...}` *even with branches that return early*. This helps me visualize the flow better. Assuming that "never executes" refers to the "return" as the question seems subtly confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if (false)` will *never* execute its body... because the value of the condition is never true. So in the code you've given, the remainder of `drawMap` will *always* execute because it will *never* return at the start.

Consider `if (x == 5)` - that will only execute if the expression `x == 5` is true. Now substitute `false` for `x == 5`...

If you want an `if` statement which will *always* execute, you want

```
if (true)
```

instead.

Comment: Urf.. There was me typing out this answer already... I just ruled out the possibility of boolean logic error for such a simple case. Code review is _hard_ for reasons completely non-technical :)

Comment: Gah, I think I had a brain fart. I feel dumb/confused. I feel dumb 'cause I understood that a false statement doesn't execute, but I simply somehow forgot, but I als ofeel confused 'cause I'm not sure if I forgot or my source code wasn't compiled and in an effort to try and fix it I tried the code I posted and brain farted and didn't realize what I did. Might be because I've been coding for 5 hours straight :X but still, thanks.  I've read like 2000 pages of C++ books... *feels terrible*

Answer (score 1):

Count me in with the crowd that didn't actually read the problem well enough, or couldn't believe that the OP didn't understand the problem if it were so simple :)

**John Skeet's answer, of course, was spot on :)**

Two thoughts:

1. If you're in a debugger, lines can *appear* to be executed, out of order, not at all or at unexpected lines when compiled with optimizations. This is because some machine instructions will get 'attributed' to different source lines. Compile without optimization to eliminate the source of confusion. It is confusing only, as optimizations should (! barring compiler bugs) not alter effective behaviour
2. It could be that you're getting an evil #define for false that you cannot trust. Rule this out by running the code through preprocessor only. `g++ -E` will do that. MSVC++ has an option to 'keep preprocessed' source

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

```
if (false)
```

is analagous to

```
if (1 == 2)
```

and will therefore never execute the next statement (or block).

In your context consider the following comments I made:

```
void drawMap(void)
{
    if (false) return; //Not gonna happen.

    //The following will always happen
    for(auto iter = this->m_layers.begin(); iter != m_layers.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if ((*iter)->get() == NULL)
            continue;
        PN::draw((*iter)->get(), b2Vec2(0,0), true, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the usage of this if(false), in a switch / case like construction like this:

```
int ret = doSomeThingFunction();
if (false) {}
else if (ret < 0 ) {

}
else if (ret == 0) {

}
else if (ret > 0) {

}
```